# why do we need remove_copy_if?

Tags: c++

according the code in http://www.cplusplus.com

```
template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
  OutputIterator remove_copy_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                                 OutputIterator result, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    if (!pred(*first)) {
      *result = *first;
      ++result;
    }
    ++first;
  }
  return result;
}

template <class InputIterator, class OutputIterator, class UnaryPredicate>
  OutputIterator copy_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                          OutputIterator result, UnaryPredicate pred)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    if (pred(*first)) {
      *result = *first;
      ++result;
    }
    ++first;
  }
  return result;
}
```

the only difference is

```
 if (!pred(*first)) //copy if is if (pred(*first)) {
```

remove_copy_if can be simulated using

```
copy_if(it1, it2, not1(pred));
```

so why do we need remove_copy_if?

Comment: simplicity, why else?

Comment: sign of bad design, algos should be implemented based on each other, not by generating plenty for every sneeze.

Comment: `copy_if` is actually the reverse of `remove_copy_if`, which was introduced first: [the proposal where `copy_if` was introduced](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2666.pdf) explains the reasons for its addition to the library *on top of* `remove_copy_if`. Pretty much, `copy_if` was introduced to remove the double negative in `remove_copy_if(first, last, not(pred))`.

Comment: Note that `std::not1` is deprecated in C++17 and requires its argument to have some extra stuff in it (`argument_type`). However, the question can stand with `std::not_fn`.

Comment: I think [Martin Fowlers piece on function lengths](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FunctionLength.html) is informative. Even if `copy_if` is simply implemented as `remove_copy_if(it1, it2, not1(pred));` or vice-versa it would still be valuable to have both because the function name better reveals the intention. There's less cognitive effort spent understanding what the code does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just so you're aware of the history, the better question would be, **Why do we need `copy_if`?**

If you look, [`remove_copy_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_copy_if/?kw=remove_copy_if) was around before [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), while [`copy_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/?kw=copy_if) made it's debut in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

You are correct that an inversion of the functor result is all that separates these 2, but the positive is far more understandable, thus `copy_if` was introduced. To quote from [JaggedSpire's link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2666.pdf):

> This is a frequently requested addition, mentioned in (for example) the latest edition of The C++ Programming Language. It is formally redundant, since it's just the inverse of `remove_copy_if`: copying all elements that satisfy a predicate p is just the same as not copying all elements that satisfy `!p`. It's worth adding anyway. First, C++ isn't really a functional language and transforming a predicate into its negation is sometimes awkward.
>   Second, the workaround of using double negatives is not unconfusing.